# How to initialize mongodb before unit-testing for javascript code?

Tags: unit-testing, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a website with nodejs+mongoose+mongodb. I'm looking for a good way to initialize the mongodb  with some prepared data.

At present, I'm doing following in `beforeEach`:

1. drop the database
2. write some code to insert some data into the database

But I found this operation is not quick enough, it takes nearly 1s.

I wonder is there any better and quicker way to prepared testing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop all collections without droping db that will not remove file and not reallocate 192 mb of space on disk.

pseudo code

```
var collections = ['collectionA', 'collectionB', 'collectionC'].
for each collection in collections 
  db[collection].drop()
```

in mongodb shell you can do db['foo'] for foo collection name. I don't know if mongoose supports this same way.

Comment: Thanks for the information of `reallocate 192 mb of space on disk`, that's helpful.